# How to pass array of addresses while testing the contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix, ethers.js

I've written a contract...

```
contract TimeLock is TimelockController {

    
    uint256 minDelay = block.timestamp + 4 minutes;


    constructor(
        address[] memory proposers,
        address[] memory executors
    ) TimelockController( minDelay, proposers, executors ) {}

    //rest of contract's code
 }
```

Now, I want to test it with mocha and javascript, so I wrote a test...

```
beforeEach(async function(){
    //const date = new Date();
    TimeLock = await ethers.getContractFactory('TimeLock');
    [proposer, executor, sendTo, admin, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();
    timelock = await TimeLock.deploy(proposer.address, executor.address);
    await timelock.deployed();
});
```

The problem, I can't figure out how to pass the array of addresses via javascript while testing my contract, with my past knowledge I'm doing it like this...

```
timelock = await TimeLock.deploy(proposer.address, executor.address);
```

and this is how my contract take addresses via constructor...

```
constructor(
            address[] memory proposers,
            address[] memory executors
        ) TimelockController( minDelay, proposers, executors ) {}
```

By giving the addresses like the above I'm getting this error...

```
1) "before each" hook for "deploys the contract":
     Error: invalid value for array (argument="value", value="0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

Can anyone please help me how to send addresses via array, Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You are supposed to be passing arrays of addresses as arguments, not addresses. Try: `await TimeLock.deploy([proposer.address], [executor.address])` as arrays with only one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract constructor expects two arrays as parameters. Your code is sending two addresses and not the arrays.

It would be something like this

```
timelock = await TimeLock.deploy([proposer.address], [executor.address]);
```